# Pandas: Calculate the difference between all rows and a specific row in the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, difference

Hi I have data in the following format:

```
   A  B
0  2  1
1  2  1
2  2  4
3  2  4
4  3  5
5  3  5
6  3  6
7  3  6
```

I want to calculate the sum of absolute differences between index 0 and all the other indexes. This means that I will calculate the difference on every column. Take the absolute value and sum those values. I want to create a column "C" that will look like this:

```
    A   B   C
0   2   1   0
1   2   1   0
2   2   4   3
3   2   4   3
4   3   5   5
5   3   5   5
6   3   6   6
7   3   6   6
```

For example,  at index 7, the calculation is done the following way:

> Index 7[C] = ABS(Index 0[A]- Index 7[A]) + ABS(Index 0[B] - Index 7[B])
>
> 6 = ABS(2-3) + ABS(1-6)

Comment: index is confused part , using the values instead

Comment: Sorry, my mistake wrote initially index 1 in the calculation when it should have been index 0...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`subtract` with `.iloc` then `sum` the absolute values across rows:

```
df['C'] = df.sub(df.iloc[0]).abs().sum(1)

   A  B  C
0  2  1  0
1  2  1  0
2  2  4  3
3  2  4  3
4  3  5  5
5  3  5  5
6  3  6  6
7  3  6  6
```

Comment: Is there a way you can specify to do this operation only on column B or only on column A?

Comment: Yes there are a few ways. Since `df.iloc[0]` is a Series, alignment is on the columns. You could for instance do `df.sub(df.iloc[0].loc[['B']])` which will then only subtract from column `B` giving you `NaN` in the other columns (as nothing aligned). This might be useful if you need to subtract A and C but perhaps don't care about column `B` (as sum will ignore the `NaN`). But perhaps for a single column you'd want: `df['B'].sub(df.B.iloc[0])`

Comment: That fits my problem perfectly. Thank you!