# Calculate the difference between all rows and a specific row in the dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, attributeerror

This is a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636573/pandas-calculate-the-difference-between-all-rows-and-a-specific-row-in-the-data) thread.

Lets consider df as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["a", 2, 3], ["b", 5, 6], ["c", 8, 9],["a", 0, 0], ["a", 8, 7], ["c", 2, 1]], columns = ["A", "B", "C"])
```

How can you calculate the difference between all rows and the row at Nth index in a group (lowest index for EACH group)  for column "B", and put it in column "D"? I want to calculate mean square displacement for my data and I want to calculate the difference of values in a column in each group with the first appeared row in that group.
I tried:

```
df['D'] = df.groupby(["A"])['B'].sub(df.groupby(['A'])["B"].iloc[0])
Group = df.groupby(["A"])
```

However using .sub and groupby raise the following error:
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'sub'

the desired result would be like this:

```
   A   B   C   D
0  a   2   3   0  *lowest index in group "a"
1  b   5   6   0  *lowest index in group "b"
2  c   8   9   0  *lowest index in group "c"
3  a   0   0  -2
4  a   8   7   6
5  c   2   1  -6
```

Comment: What formula did you use to compute first value (i.e the "0") in column D ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this answer could be enough of a hint for you:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["a", 2, 3], ["b", 5, 6], ["c", 8, 9],["a", 0, 0], ["a", 8, 7], ["c", 2, 1]], columns = ["A", "B", "C"])
print("df:")
print(df)
print()

groupA = df.groupby(['A'])
print("groupA:")
print(groupA.groups)
print()

print("lowest indices for each group from columnA:")
lowest_indices = dict()
for k, v in groupA.groups.items():
    lowest_indices[k] = v[0]
print(lowest_indices)
print()

columnB = df['B']
print("columnB:")
print(columnB)
print()

df['D'] = df['B']

for i in range(len(df)):
    group_at_i = df['A'].iloc[i]
    
    lowest_index_of_that = lowest_indices[group_at_i]
    b_element_at_that_index = df['B'].iloc[lowest_index_of_that]
    the_difference = df['B'].iloc[i] - b_element_at_that_index
    df.loc[i, 'D'] = the_difference
    
print("df:")
print(df)
```